# .NET MAUI 7 - Button in AbsoluteLayout not working in Android

Tags: c#, android, maui

As shown below, I created a button in the lower right corner with an absolute layout. The thing is, it doesn't work on Android. It shows up but instead presses the recipe below. On Windows App everything is working as expected.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<FlexLayout>
    <RefreshView IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}" Command="{Binding RefreshRecipes}">

        <CollectionView >
            ...
        </CollectionView>
    </RefreshView>
    <AbsoluteLayout MaximumWidthRequest="0" >
        <Button AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 1, 100, 100"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                Text="+"
                Command="{Binding AddRecipeCommand}"
                FontSize="Large"
                BackgroundColor="DodgerBlue"
                TextColor="White"
                CornerRadius="25"
                HeightRequest="50"
                WidthRequest="50" 
                ZIndex="100"/>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</FlexLayout>
```

I'm aware the `MaximumWidthRequest="0"` might cause a problem, but I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the FlexLayout to a Grid. Then you delete the AbsoluteLayout and set the VerticalOptions and the HorizontalOptions to End.
That is the way how I do it.

If this doesn't work, you have to show your xaml.cs code and the ViewModel code.

Comment: **1)** Please show a bit of code, to go with your description. **2)** To clarify: `Grid` makes it possible for two elements to be overlaid "one on top of the other", by giving them the same Column and Row values. In this simple case, can omit Column and Row; both will default to "0".